# Can't Open folder

Tags: raspbian

I use rasp pi 4 as same as I did every day but today I can't open my folder when I try to open it, It'll open for 1 sec and then refresh and close itself and I try another folder but it happens again what happen to my rasp pi

Comment: I open a folder on my Rpi4B like this: GUI Desktop > Accessories > File Manager > /home/pi.  Can you reach the last step?

Comment: What folder do you mean?

Comment: Several posts recently on the RPF forum. Apparently `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade` solves the problem.

Answer (score 7):

I've had the same issue, what fixed the problem was entering:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall pcmanfm
```

into the terminal.

Comment: Clarification: `pcmanfm` is the default file manager on Raspbian, which is why reinstalling it fixes the problem.

Comment: Perfect! It works again, after a reboot

Comment: It worked for me as well on a RPi 3 B+.